# Using jQuery plugin imported with Browserify

Tags: jquery, browserify

I am trying to begin using Browserify in a project but I am a bit confused how to actually use plugins that are imported into my script using `require()`.

Specifically, I am trying to use the fullCalendar plugin -

```
var fullCalendar = require('fullcalendar')
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({});
});
```

When this loads, I get an error that `fullCalendar` is not defined. If you import a jQuery plugin using this method is it then called differently? If so, how?

I am using Laravel Elixir (gulp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
global.$ = require('jquery'); // or global.jQuery
require('fullcalendar');
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974054/why-doesnt-this-jquery-plugin-need-a-shim-in-order-to-work) for more information.